# UIStepper moves out from screen, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistepper

I have an `UIStepper` in tableView. It is in a container view, but that one has correctly set up, with constraints etc.

Any idea what is the problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the constraints for the label? If the width is not fixed in some way, it may be growing and moving everything to the right...

Comment: Did you try changing the priority of the constraints? I don't think the constraint for the `UIStepper` width is needed (should be its intrinsic size)

Answer (score 0):

You constraint for First `UILable` may having Expandable Width, which leads to move next three controller to move aside, eventually next controls moves its position by `frame.x` increasing.

You can stop first `UILable` to increase width by deleting Adjust width constraint. Alternate to change width, you can size down the font size and increase number of lines.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: what you mean 'deleting Adjust width constraint'?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add width constrain to `UIStepper`. It is not strait forward that it has a 94px width, it has to be specified.